# How to get latitude and longitude from Google Map

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps

I'm planning to use [gmaps](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) inside a Qt application via `QWebView`. User should be able navigate any place on the map. Then clicking on a button, application stores latitude and longitude of center of the map into a file.

How can I get geographical location from the map inside webview into C++ side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supposing you have set up a QWebView containing a gmaps map and a QPushButton to be able to retrieve the lat long of the center of the map, you could do the following:

connect the clicked() signal of the button with a slot, for i.e. void getMapCenter();
Supposing that the gmaps map div is #map, the code would look like that:

```
void MainWindow::getMapCenter(){
    QVariant lat = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("map.map.center.d");
    QVariant lon = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("map.map.center.e");

    //Test
    qDebug() << "latitude:" << lat.toString() << "longitude:" << lon.toString();

    //do some processing here with lat and lon
}
```

Comment: I think `d` stands for longitude and `e` is for latitude. Is that correct?

Comment: No i'm pretty sure it's the opposite.. Here you can test it here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U94Tv/)